# Reverse a Cross Tabulation or Frequency Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Suppose I have a frequency table `df` defined as:

```
dat = [[0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 3], [4, 1, 1]]
idx = pd.Index([*'abc'], name='One')
col = pd.Index([*'xyz'], name='Two')
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, idx, col)

df

Two  x  y  z
One         
a    0  2  1
b    1  0  3
c    4  1  1
```

How do I "invert" this to get a dataframe `pre_df`

```
   One Two
0    a   y
1    a   y
2    a   z
3    b   x
4    b   z
5    b   z
6    b   z
7    c   x
8    c   x
9    c   x
10   c   x
11   c   y
12   c   z
```

Such that `pd.crosstab(pre_df.One, pre_df.Two)` would get me back to `df`

```
Two  x  y  z
One         
a    0  2  1
b    1  0  3
c    4  1  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `stack` and `repeat`:

```
s = df.stack()
s.index.repeat(s).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   One Two
0    a   y
1    a   y
2    a   z
3    b   x
4    b   z
5    b   z
6    b   z
7    c   x
8    c   x
9    c   x
10   c   x
11   c   y
12   c   z
```